# Windows registry file paths, outside sys32?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-registry

In HKLM, there are various places where drivers are specified. Like "ImagePath"
that is "system32\DRIVERS\something.sys".

I've tried to change those to mapped drives and UNC paths, but it doesn't work. Also, note the path starts "system32", not "C:...", or "%systemroot%".

Is it possible for those kind of paths to point to a network share somewhere?

Comment: Since they are not complete paths, my first guess would be no. I'm just wondering why in the world you would want to though.

Comment: it would make an easy way to enable/disable usb storage on a network, without reboots. otherwise i've gotta write to the user machines drive, which is do-able, but not as slick.

Answer (score 0):

No. these paths are concatenated with the %windir% (seriously, don't change %windir%/%systemroot%). Keep in mind, messing with this too much will prevent you from loading your network card drivers in the first place, leading to complete failure. Also I think Windows File Protection and systemstate would seriously freak out.

Comment: well thats poopy. it would make an easy way to enable/disable usb storage on a network, without reboots. thanks!